# Heroku/Zurb Foundation Sass SyntaxError in Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, zurb-foundation

My app is throwing this error when I try to push to Heroku. It looks like the culprit is a rogue !global line in a stylesheet somewhere, but I'm not sure where the source code lives.

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...odules, $name) ": expected "}", was "!global;"
   (in /tmp/build_6cf14c02-e49b-44e7-819c-871d5da3cf73/app/assets/stylesheets/framework_and_overrides.css.scss:13)
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try going to line 13 of app/assets/stylesheets/framework_and_overrides.css.scss and seeing if the error is there?

Comment: Yes, but I suspect it's the imported "foundation" sheet that's causing the problem

Comment: What version of Sass are you using?

Comment: 3.4.2, although I don't have it specified in my Gemfile.

Comment: Is your sass restricted to 3.2.19 in your gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 9):

Change your foundation-rails gem from 5.4.4.0 to 5.4.3.1 in your gem file

gem 'foundation-rails', '5.4.3.1'

then run

bundle update

This should do it for now tell they fix it :)

**Additionally:**

As for finding the file "bundle show foundation-rails" use the finder "Go to folder" to the path and find "_function.scss" it is under vendor assets stylesheets foundation   _function.scss

Both of my answers could be found in the link by gustavo-beathyate

As for heroku error 
make sure if your adding any thing to the assets to use

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

and then

also when you push use -f

```
git push -f heroku master
```

if not only use

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Comment: Do you have something to refer to to get more details on this?

Comment: You should not create new answers to add information, you can edit your own answer to perform this function.

Comment: Thanks Knossos sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19222-sass-syntax-error-on-rails

You basically have to open the gem and modify **line 13** in `_functions.scss`, removing the call to `!global`.

Comment: Hmm, I did this previously and it got the app to run on my local machine. `!global` is no longer there when I open `_functions.scss` now, but the error still comes up when I try and deploy to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been fixed with [v5.4.5](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/releases/tag/v5.4.5) of Foundation. See also [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5811#issuecomment-56975540) for some more background on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting your exact error after I upgraded to foundation-rails 5.5.0.0.  I updated the sass-rails gem per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807138/1753903 and the error went away.