# Sass or Foundation Error after updating Rails and other gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

I have recently updated rails and some other gems. However now I get the following error:

> Sass::SyntaxError at / Mixin "exports" does not accept a content
>   block.   (in
>   /Users/mikhailja/Sites/marketing/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:341)

I'm using:

- ruby 2.1.2
- rails 4.1.8
- sass 3.2.2
- sass-rails 2.0.0
- foundation-rails 5.4.5.0

The problem went away for a while after trying numerous gem versions but now all of a sudden its back after getting a **stack level too deep** error.

I've tried the same version of foundation in a new app and it works perfectly.

Any help to get to the bottom of this problem would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/331-scss-will-not-compile and https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2128

Comment: I've tried updating the sass gem as mentioned in your first link, that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: The second link has a lot of suggestions to change how foundation is imported but none of them seem to make a difference and I think that's not the problem because it did work for a while. It must be an environment related issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Here is what I did for anyone else experiencing this problem:

1. Downgraded foundation-rails gem to version 5.1.1.0 (this was my original version) at this point my rails server would not start properly.
2. Then updated foundation-rails to version 5.3.0.0

I'm not sure if there was just a gem version compatibility issue or if the downgrade/upgrade made the difference.

Anyway, now everything works and my tests are passing!

Comment: The issue I was getting was ActionView errors: `ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;"` You answer solved my problem. I can only speculate that there seem to be some issues with foundation-rails 5.5.0.0, Rails 4.1.8, and SASS 3.2.2.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Foundation [github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6148) repo, it has to do with a Rails and Sass compatibility issue, which creates a Foundation compatibility issue because of their codebase.  Apparently sass-rails has been recently updated to deal with this, and should solve the issue, but I'm not seeing any updates when I update my gems, so best way to deal with it now is probably to downgrade.

Edit: figured it out. In your Gemfile delete the specified version of sass-rails that's autogenerated then run update and you'll get the newest version which will work with the newest version of foundation.